# MySQL MacOS X Catalina InnoDB Location of database file

Tags: mysql, macos, file, location, innodb

The standard location for the database is /usr/local/mysql/data but when I look in finder I can not see it - /usr/ is a hidden folder but Cmd-shift-G displays it
So why can I not see the db file ?

Comment: You closed your eyes?  

Comment: Try `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%datadir%';`. It might be that your system does not have the 'standard location' ?

Comment: No Luuk the /usr/local/mysql/data is empty

Comment: +---------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                  |
+---------------+------------------------+
| datadir       | /usr/local/mysql/data/ |
+---------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: OK Folk - it is an Access Rights Problem - I made copy of the folder and found that I could see a whole lot of files including files for the tables in my database as *.lbd. in a sub-folder with th datsbase name The only thing I did not see anywhere in /usr/local/mysql/data/ was an *.mdb file with the database name. IS THIS RIGHT ?